# Using a RelativeLayout as the layout for a ListView

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public class Events extends ListActivity {

//...

 private static String[] FROM = {_ID,TIME,TITLE};
 private static int[] TO = {R.id.rowid,R.id.time,R.id.title,};
 private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {       
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

The R.layout.item is defined as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowidcolon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text=": "
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowid" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowidcolon" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/timecolon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text=": "
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timecolon" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

So my problem is that when I run this program, the only thing that is displayed in the list is the Row ID textview. None of the text views that come after it are displayed. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

tell the row id TextView to be the same size as the parent RelativeLayout. If you want all the TextViews to be laid out horizontally you should  use a LinearLayout as the parent, and set `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using android:`layout_width="wrap_content"` for each of the TextViews although I suspect you'll also have to do other formatting to get each to be the correct width depending on if the content text length is variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your TextViews should have wrap_content as their width, not match_parent.  This layout is probably easier in a horizontal LinearLayout.  Note that using the hierarchy viewer can sometimes make this kind of problem easy to discover.

Comment: Thank you this solution works as well. I had no idea something like the "hierarchy viewer" existed, this will be very useful for me :)